# Send a Google Analytics custom metric once with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

With Google Universal Analytics you can send custom metric in two ways:

1) Attached to a specific hit

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'metric1':  1
});
```

2) Or you can set custom metric globally, so the custom metric will be send with all the hits on the page.

```
ga('set', 'metric1':  1);
```

In this second case, every hit of the page (eg: an event) will add a value `1` to the custom metric `metric1`.

In google Tag Manager you can set custom metric in the configuration panel, but this set a "global" custom metric: every hit on the page will increment the given metric (case 2).

Is there a way to send a single metric with a pageview in Google Tag Manager (like in case 1)?

Answer (score 0):

In Google Tag Manager, you can create a Tag that will send Pageviews and also have it set Custom Metrics at the same time.

To configure the Tag, set:

- **Track Type** to *Page View*
- Twirl down *More settings*
- Twirl down *Custom Metrics*
- Click *+ Add Custom Metric*
- Set your Metric Index and Value

Comment: Thank you Philippe, but this sets a global custom metric for the page. Every other hit in the page (like an event, or a transaction) will add a new value to the index. I want to send a custom metric just once.

Comment: @Francesco, are you sure about this? Philippe's answer sound correct to me as the metric is only set for the specific pageview tag, and nothing else. It's not going to be set with any other tag that it's not configured in.

Comment: Other that what I suggested, the only other thing I can think of is adding a new *Fields to Set* with *cm1* as *Name* and *1* as *Value*... While it is correctly listed in the [Analytics Field Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#customs), I am not sure if it is supported by Tag Manager, as it is not listed in the drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

@Francesco Create a user-defined variable and name it "custom metric1". Set it to type "Lookup Table", input Value "{{url path}}". Add the path to the pages you want it to fire on as inputs, set the output as "1", and define a default value of "0".

Now set the custom metric in your GA tag like Philippe described but make sure to set the metric value to {{custom metric1}}.

The custom metric is now always added but adds "0" to pages you are not listing in the lookup page.